# How to preform JOIN with JPA JAVA

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa

I want to be short and clear for my problem.. I am trying to retrieve datas from the database performing join to get the result I want..

So i have 3 tables ,

```
EMPLOYEE:
emp_id -- PK
name..
surname..
dob.. etc
```

USER:

```
UserID PK
Username
Pass
emp_id fk
role_id fk
```

Role

```
RoleID pk
Description
```

I want to perform a  query to get a list of employees who are users ,and have roleid =2;
How can I do that on JPA

I tried this

```
Select e from Employee e JOIN User u Join Role r where r.roleId = 2
```

But it doesn't work still gets all employees without filtering those who have ID=2

Thanks y'all

Comment: *"But it doesn't work still gets all employees without filtering those who have ID=2"* you forgot the `ON` clause, it seams your database is now executing it as a `CROSS JOIN` instead.. Iám pretty much tempted of voteclosing this question to be a simple typographical error

Comment: If that does not help or you can figure it out..i advice you to read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.

Comment: Select * from Employee e inner join User u on e.emp_id= pr.emp_id inner join 
Role r on 
on r.roleID= u.roleId
where r.roleID =2
I tried this query in SQL , and it worked perfectly this is what I am tryign to retrieve in JPA

Comment: @RaymondNijland nope this is not SQL query but JPA query is not the same , I read that you shouldn't specify On clause

Comment: in that case i voteclose the question as *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Answer (score 0):

You have to set associations between your entities i.e. define how your two entities are linked to each other. This way spring will be able to convert jpql into sql and get data.

You will have to write your User and Employee entity like

```
public class User {
...
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn //using which column name it should join
private Employee employee;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Role role;
...
```

```
public class Employee {
...
@OneToOne(mapedBy="employee")
private User user;
...
```

then you can write your query like

```
@Query("select e from Employee e LEFT JOIN e.user u LEFT JOIN u.role r where r.id = :roleId")
List<Employee> getEmployeeListByRoleId(@Param("roleId") Long roleId);
```